# Can asyncPipe in angular2 can improve UI performance?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

In the [Tour Of Heros angular2 example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/), the retrieved data via promise is extracted as `Hero[]` as described in *[Extracting the data in the then callback](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html)*. Instead of that extraction logic, an `Observable` can be used with an impure [asyncPipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html).

Is there any UI performance gain if I use `Observable`? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the components `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`  to avoid unnecessary change detection runs for this component and its children. The `|async` pipe then calls `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` to register the component for change detection in the next change detection cycle, but only when new values arrive. 
This way change detection work is reduced notably because it's only run when necessary, which improves performance.